# Force execution of a specified S3 method

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-s3

I am using the {patchwork} package internally in my package. I would like to utilize the patchwork arithmetic operators (ie `|`, `\`, etc).

I export methods for my class of objects. For example:

```r
"|.ggsurvfit" <- function(e1, e2) {
  build_and_wrap(e1) | build_and_wrap(e2)
}
```

In the example above, when a figure of class 'ggsurvfit' is passed, it is processed and converted to class 'ggplot', then executed with the patchwork method `"|.ggplot"`.

The issue I am encountering is that users need to combine a typical ggplot with a ggsurvfit plot. For example `p1 | p2` where p1 has class 'ggplot' and `p2` has class 'ggsurvfit'. The patchwork package exports a `|.ggplot` method which is being used. But we get an error because the `|.ggplot` doesn't know how to do the processing needed for the second argument that is class 'ggsurvfit'.

I am trying to write an S3 method `|.ggplot` that would handle the second argument appropriately. But I can't get anything to work...ugh!

Is there a way to force execution of some code via a specified S3 method, i.e. how can I force execution with patchwork's `|.ggplot` method?

```r
"|.ggplot" <- function(e1, e2) {
  e2 <- build_and_wrap(e2) # process the second argument

  # patch together the figures using the patwork `|.ggplot` method
  withr::with_namespace(
    package = "patchwork",
    code = e1 | e2
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried ```code = e1 `|.ggplot` e2```? Or ```code = e1 patchwork::`|.ggplot` e2```

Comment: Yeah I tried a few variations on this, and always get the error `Error: '|.ggplot' is not an exported object from 'namespace:patchwork'`. I think the issue is that S3 methods are not exported by packages; rather, the generic may be exported and then the S3 method dispatched. Regardless, it's tricky!

Comment: In what package can `build_and_wrap` be found?

Comment: That is an internal function in the ggsurvfit package. https://github.com/ddsjoberg/ggsurvfit/blob/dfa9a21ff3906604ca346cf27f14dc73463d74c1/R/ggsurvfit_arithmetic.R#L117

For now, it only lives in this pull request branch FYI https://github.com/ddsjoberg/ggsurvfit/pull/115

Answer (score 2):

S3 is not designed for multiple dispatch.  S4 is.  A principled approach would be to define `ggsurvfit` as an S4 subclass of `ggplot`, and then define suitable S4 methods for `|` (or any other internally generic binary operator).

```r
setOldClass("ggplot")
setClass("ggsurvfit", contains = "ggplot", slots = c(p = "ggplot"))

setMethod("|", c("ggplot", "ggsurvfit"), 
          function(e1, e2) <do stuff with e1   and e2@p here>)
setMethod("|", c("ggsurvfit", "ggplot"), 
          function(e1, e2) <do stuff with e1@p and e2   here>)
setMethod("|", c("ggsurvfit", "ggsurvfit"), 
          function(e1, e2) <do stuff with e1@p and e2@p here>)
```

Your package's `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE` files would need to change accordingly.

We can test that this works with a simple example.  Here, classes `a` and `b` take the place of classes `ggplot` and `ggsurvfit`, and the S3 method `|.a` takes the place of `|.ggplot` from **patchwork**:

```r
setOldClass("a")
setClass("b", contains = "a", slots = c(p = "a"))

.S3method("|",   "a",       function(e1, e2) "aa")
setMethod("|", c("a", "b"), function(e1, e2) "ab")
setMethod("|", c("b", "a"), function(e1, e2) "ba")
setMethod("|", c("b", "b"), function(e1, e2) "bb")

a <- structure(1, class = "a")
b <- new("b", p = structure(2, class = "a"))

a | a
## [1] "aa"
a | b
## [1] "ab"
b | a
## [1] "ba"
b | b
## [1] "bb"
```

For more details about hybrid use of S3 and S4, you can take a look at `?Methods_for_S3`, `?setOldClass`, and `?S3Part`.

Comment: Thank you! I"ll take a look and let you know!

Comment: If you decide to keep the S3 approach of masking **patchwork**'s `|.ggplot` with your own, then you can also try `get("|.ggplot", asNamespace("patchwork"), mode = "function")(e1, e2)` in your method.  You don't really want/need to be using **withr**.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work.
Instead of overloading the operator `|.ggplot`, define a new generic using the standard R syntax for infix operators, then define a method for objects of class `"ggplot"`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsurvfit)
library(patchwork)

"%|%" <- function(e1, ...) UseMethod("%|%", e1)
"%|%.ggplot" <- function(e1, e2) {
  #e2 <- build_and_wrap(e2) # process the second argument
  
  # patch together the figures using the patwork `|.ggplot` method
  withr::with_namespace(
    package = "patchwork",
    code = e1 | e2
  )
}

g1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
g2 <- survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df_lung) |>
  ggsurvfit()

g1 %|% g2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Here is another idea. In the new method body there is no need to use the infix notation to call `patchwork:::|.ggplot`, so, don't.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsurvfit)
library(patchwork)

"|.ggplot" <- function(e1, e2) {
  #e2 <- build_and_wrap(e2) # process the second argument
  
  # patch together the figures using the patwork `|.ggplot` method
  withr::with_namespace(
    package = "patchwork",
    code = patchwork:::`|.ggplot`(e1, e2)
  )
}

g1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
g2 <- survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df_lung) |>
  ggsurvfit()

g1 | g2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Rui for investigating! If I change the function name and don't use the more commonly known generic people are using from patchwork, you're correct that we can avoid the conflict between my implementation of the S3 method and the S3 method from patchwork. I really do hope, however, I can find a solution that does not require a new generic and S3 method name.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg With `|.ggplot` I was getting a stack overflow error. It is calling itself recursively.